# Javascript Image Preview on multiple Input files

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, input, preview

How do I preview the images on multiple input files.

html:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
   <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
   <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
   <input type='file' id="imgInp2" />
   <img id="blah2" src="#" alt="your image" />
   <input type='file' id="imgInp3" />
   <img id="blah3" src="#" alt="your image" />
</form>
```

jquery:

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#imgInp").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
```

That code worked on one input type file, but I do not know how to modifiy it to get more then one preview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use common classes to group the elements. That way you can have a single event handler. You can then find the `img` element from the current `input` using `next()`. Try this:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <input type='file' class="imgInp" />
    <img class="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
    <input type='file' class="imgInp" />
    <img class="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
    <input type='file' class="imgInp" />
    <img class="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
</form>
```

```js
function readURL() {
    var $input = $(this);
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            $input.next('.blah').attr('src', e.target.result).show();
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    }
}

$(".imgInp").change(readURL);
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/97dzkf70)

Comment: Thanks worked, you may know a way to show pdfs and doc files aswell?

Comment: I don't believe that's possible, at least not very reliably. You could potentially do it in an iframe, but it would depend on the users' browser settings whether or not the file is downloaded or displayed.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan your script has a bug, but I do not know why, if one picks a file which is e.g. bigger then 2gigs one gets an error

Comment: That's a browser/OS implementation issue. Frankly if you need to transfer 2Gb files, uploading through a web browser is the last way you should be doing it.

Answer (score 1):

> `id` selector(`#`) will select only first matched element.

Use `$('input[type="file"]')` to select all elements having type as `file`

*[`.next(selector)`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) will return immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements*

Try this:

```js
function readURL(input) {
  var elem = $(input);
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      elem.next('img').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(elem.get(0).files[0]);
  }
}

$("input[type='file']").change(function() {
  readURL(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
  <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
  <input type='file' id="imgInp2" />
  <img id="blah2" src="#" alt="your image" />
  <input type='file' id="imgInp3" />
  <img id="blah3" src="#" alt="your image" />
</form>
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/dp5u2v95/)